# Are Java varargs received in the same order in which they were given?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I can't find any documentation on this issue.

In some `Lists` and `Maps`, the order of the elements is random and is not the same order in which they were added to the list / map. Is that true about var args, or are they received in the same order in which they were sent?

E.g, I have a form validation method, which takes a field name and a vararg list of rules. If I supply the rules: `Rules.INT, Rules.MAX.arg(100)`, then I would want the `Rules.INT` rule to be checked first, before the `Rules.MAX` rule is checked, because `Rules.MAX` assumes that the given value is a proper integer. Hence if `Rules.INT` fails, then `Rules.MAX` would not be called - however if the varargs are received in a random order, then `Rules.MAX` may get called before `Rules.INT` anyway, and could then throw up an exception if the value is not an integer, which is what I don't want.

Edit: Here's my method with the var args, for clarification:

```
public boolean validate(String name, Rule... rules)
{
   String value = getValue(name);
   for (Rule rule : rules)
   {
     if (! rule.match(value) )
        return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Now, if I called this method by: `validate("age", Rule.INT, Rule.MAX.arg(100) )`, can I be sure that `Rule.INT` will be iterated / checked before `Rule.MAX` in the `validate()` method?

Comment: i'll be interested in answer

Comment: I would think the answer is yes, since `Rule...` is equivalently the same data type as `Rule[]` - i.e. an array, with ordering.

Comment: The answer is yes.  Java doesn't go shuffling method arguments around.

Comment: An answer that references the relevant section of the JLS will be much more useful than a mere assertion abount the ordering.

Comment: @Raedwald Feel free to post it, right now Rohit's answer is only talking about the evaluation order, while my question is about the receiving order.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*All* method arguments are received in the order specified, whether varargs or otherwise. Under the hood, a varargs parameter is an array of the specified argument type, not a collection of any kind which could upset the order in the source text.